# How to edit the window layout in Magento

Tags: magento

Inside the folder structure of Magento, which is the file that I must edit to change the shop window:

[image]

I am editing the file list.phtml in the following path:

```
app/design/frontend/MEU_TEMA/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

- But no changes take effect ...

** I need to add an HTML block below the price.

Comment: Charles, if you are using MEU_TEMA as theme the path above is correct, please try to clear cache etc to see the effects.

Comment: I cleaned all the cache but did not solve it yet. Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin panel - system - design , check theme path.
If you using rwd theme , go to folder -design/frontend/rwd/default/template.

Or you can change your default theme in admin panel to your custom -MEU_TEMA

Answer (score 0):

Next idea..
Go to design/frontend/YOUR_THEME/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

And make changes.

And another way declare new block and input it ,into view.phtml  like : getChildBlock(yours_block_path);